# saveAsync returns error

Tags: outlook, office-js

I'm using JavaScript API for Office to save email into draft.
To do so, I invoke [saveAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#saveAsync) method from Outlook Web Add-in.

Most of the time, the method returns **itemId** as expected. But some times, it returns "**Internal format error**". It's really random and I still cannot find a way to reproduce the error.

I'm working with Outlook 2016 Online for Windows (Office 365 ProPlus Version 1711).

Any one has this error before?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which Outlook clients and versions do you see this for? For drafts you see this for, do you see this error consistently?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I'm working with Outlook 2016 Online for Windows. The error happens once in a while. Average of 1/20

Comment: What's the version of your Outlook 2016 Online for Windows? When it happens for a draft, does it then consistently fail for that same draft? Or it can succeed for the same draft if you re-try?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  Checked outlook and I got this: Office 365 ProPlus Version 1711. If I attempt to save draft a second time it will go through. So no, it does not consistently fail.

Comment: Does this happen on the first compose message that you create? (and then succeed every time after that?). Is it possible that you are calling saveAsync before Initialize has been completed?

Comment: No It happens randomly not only the first compose message. If I try to call saveAsync a second time, it will work

Comment: Just want to double check here. Are you using the Desktop Client? Or Outlook inside a browser (IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, etc).

Comment: Either way, does this error happen on both Desktop Win32 Client and Browser clients? Or just one or the other.